# Env variables not showing in `printenv`

Tags: bash, terminal, github-actions

(Added bash and terminal tags since I'm unsure if my issue is specific to Github actions specifically or if instead is a misunderstanding on how env vars work more generally)

I'm working on a workflow.yml and in a step "Env substitue in sql script" am trying to set some env vars:

```
on: [push]

env:
  GAME: "FunGame"
  TRAIN_HORIZON: 7

jobs:
  ssql:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Get data
    steps:
      - name: Checkout cum-rev repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2 # Defaults to current repo - check out current repo
      - name: Checkout ds-ssql-gh-action
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          repository: ourorg/ds-ssql-gh-action
          token: ${{ secrets.cumrev_workflow_token }}
          ref: main
          path: './ds-ssql-gh-action'
      - name: Env substitue in sql script
        run: |
            INSTALL_DATE=$(date -d "`date +%Y%m01` -12 month" +%Y-%m-%d)
            echo "Here is install date $INSTALL_DATE"
            IOS_GAME="${{ env.GAME }}_IOS_PROD"
            ANDROID_GAME="${{ env.GAME }}_ANDROID_PROD"
            envsubst < get-data/training-data.sql
            cat get-data/training-data.sql
            printenv
```

After pushing this the job attempts to run. I `printenv` at the bottom and when I see the env variables, I don't see any of `INSTALL_DATE`, `IOS_GAME` or `ANDROID_GAME`.

Why are those env variables not being set with the lines:

```
        INSTALL_DATE=$(date -d "`date +%Y%m01` -12 month" +%Y-%m-%d)
        echo "Here is install date $INSTALL_DATE"
        IOS_GAME="${{ env.GAME }}_IOS_PROD"
        ANDROID_GAME="${{ env.GAME }}_ANDROID_PROD"
```

Note line `echo "Here is install date $INSTALL_DATE"` does indeed print out the correct value as expected. But it's not showing when I run `printenv`?

Comment: You forgot to place the variables into the environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to export the variables you want to see in the environment:

```
export INSTALL_DATE=$(date -d "`date +%Y%m01` -12 month" +%Y-%m-%d)
...
```